# How to prevent my csv_writer variable from preventing the reading section of my code from running correctly?

Tags: python, csv

I am attempting to create a csv file and store names, email addresses and phone numbers in it before reading that file and putting the data into a list and outputting it. However, if I do not overwrite my csv_writer variable to be blank (csv_writer = "") the reading section does not iterate through the file and instead does jumps over and outputs an empty list. The presence of this csv_writer variable not being empty causes my csv_reader variable to hold <_csv.reader object at 0x0000019A529D7EE0> instead of <_csv.Dialect object at 0x000002C86E6921C0>. My code is below if it helps.

```
# Writing to CSV files

import csv

headings = ["Name", "Email", "Phone"]
names_list = [["Fred","fred@fred.com","01909-9098645"], ["Sue","sue@sue.com","01986-3937586"], ["John","john@john.com","01892-3983753"], ["Beth","beth@beth.com","230492843"], ["beth","bth@3409ldf","3098430432"], ["Bob","bob@bob.com","2304982304"], ["Joe","joe*0394","230482304"]]
csv_file = open("names.csv", "w", newline = "")
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ",", quotechar = "|")
csv_writer.writerow(headings)
for data in names_list:
    csv_writer.writerow(data)

csv_file.close





csv_writer = "" # Removing this causes the following code to malfunction (outputting [])



# Reading CSV files

import csv

names_list = []
csv_file = open("names.csv", "r", newline = "")
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = ",", quotechar = "|")
for data in csv_reader: # This is the loop which gets skipped when csv_writer doesn't get overwritten
    if csv_reader.line_num == 1:
        headings = [data[0], data[1], data[2]]
    else:
        name = [data[0], data[1], data[2]]
        names_list.append(name)

 csv_file.close

 print(names_list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not closing your files properly with `csv_file.close` vs `csv_file.close()`.  there were some other indentation issues, but maybe that is just due to the site.
working revision: https://onlinegdb.com/kdB73BBAi

```py
import csv

# Writing to CSV files
headings = ["Name", "Email", "Phone"]
names_list = [["Fred","fred@fred.com","01909-9098645"], ["Sue","sue@sue.com","01986-3937586"], ["John","john@john.com","01892-3983753"], ["Beth","beth@beth.com","230492843"], ["beth","bth@3409ldf","3098430432"], ["Bob","bob@bob.com","2304982304"], ["Joe","joe*0394","230482304"]]
csv_file = open("names.csv", "w", newline = "")
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ",", quotechar = "|")
csv_writer.writerow(headings)
for data in names_list:
    csv_writer.writerow(data)

csv_file.close()

# Reading CSV files
names_list = []
csv_file = open("names.csv", "r", newline = "")
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = ",", quotechar = "|")
for data in csv_reader:
    if csv_reader.line_num == 1:
        headings = [data[0], data[1], data[2]]
    else:
        name = [data[0], data[1], data[2]]
        names_list.append(name)

csv_file.close()

print(names_list)
```

Comment: omg thanks, how did I miss that

Comment: @AlexParker, if this answer was the solution to your problem, please accept it by clicking the checkmark at the top-left of the answer. Thank you.